# bootstrap reduce row padding

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.x with a table definition like this

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
```

Pretty standard stuff

I want to reduce the default vertical padding on the cells - want to reduce the padding on cells further. I know that table-condensed reduces the vertical padding by 50%. I want to reduce it to just 1px.

Where do I make the change?  I have tried going through bootstrap.min.css but can't find anything to modify there - nothing I understand

Many thanks in advance

Best wishes

Iyer

Comment: Why not simply add your own class to the tables to do what you want? Bootstrap is a starting baseline, not the end.

Comment: Did you try customizing it: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#tables

Comment: vogomatix : Very new to HTML/CSS - am running blind and am trying to learn and develop.  Many thanks for your respose

Comment: cmmi : Yes, I tried everything I could - and then posted - very new to HTML/CSS.  Learning and developing.  Thanks  alot

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's pretty easy if you know how to use inspector tool of your browser (*Right click->Inspect Element*). If you want to learn CSS this would be a very important tool.

So find this property:

```
.table-condensed>thead>tr>th, .table-condensed>tbody>tr>th, .table-condensed>tfoot>tr>th, .table-condensed>thead>tr>td, .table-condensed>tbody>tr>td, .table-condensed>tfoot>tr>td{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

which has `padding: 5px;`, change it to 1px.

Here's how it **[looks](http://jsfiddle.net/4ffLK/)** when changed.

Answer (score 5):

Note - Instead of modifying the .table-condensed class which will all tables which use this bootstrap class, it could be more advantageous to make another class (say table_morecondensed ) as below...

```
.table_morecondensed>thead>tr>th, 
.table_morecondensed>tbody>tr>th, 
.table_morecondensed>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table_morecondensed>thead>tr>td, 
.table_morecondensed>tbody>tr>td, 
.table_morecondensed>tfoot>tr>td{ padding: 2px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 "Inspect Element" ... tells you exactly what the settings are per element and where they are coming from.  Invaluable tool for working with the layout.

As for customizing Bootstrap (v3 at least), I believe Site.css is the local site-level override file ... so DO NOT change the core bootstrap css files ... instead just add override styles into Site.css and make that your personal file.  If the style overrides don't appear to take, add the !important tag to them.  And if you ever update your bootstrap package be sure to save a copy of your Site.css so you can reapply your customizations.